# Android In-App Billing - Multiple accounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a problem with In-App billing when ppl use multiple devices with multiple users.

Scenario:

```
User: Nick    
Device Nexus 4 and Nexus 10    
Google Accounts: Nick's private Google account and Nick's business Google account.    
Nick's Nexus 4 has just the private account activated. His tablet has both activated.
```

Nick bought an item via in-app billing which removes the ads in an app on his Nexus 4 with his private Google Account.

When using his Nexus 10 the app he just bought still displays ads.

The reason is that when quering if the user has bought the app, the In-App billing will perform the request with his business account (on the tablet it's his primary account) and not with his private account.

So I was wondering, is there any possibility to perform this query for both accounts?

Some of my users have this problem and they don't want to buy the app twice.

Comment: I see no reason why they should not buy the app twice.  In accordance with Play store Ts&Cs, apps are per user account.

Comment: Yeah and they are using the same account on two devices.

Comment: Well, I'm confused.  Apps, and in app purchases, are common to all devices using the account. Please try to rephrase your question.  It seems that you are asking how the same person can share apps and purchases across accounts, which they cannot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does In App Billing support multiple accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263889/does-in-app-billing-support-multiple-accounts)