# Android InAppBilling, is there any possibility to detect getPurchased item from different device with same google account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

In my application, i have implement `InAppBilling (V3)` Feature...
   if i Logged in `*abc@gmail.com*` account in *Device A* , then purchased
   item from my application , and then if i call `getPurchase()` method
   then it will return purchased item ..
 if i Logged in *Device B*
   with same account it and if i call `getPurchase()` then it will not
   display the item which i already purchased in *Device A* ..

```
private void checkownedItems() {
    try {
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(),"inapp", null);

        if (ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0) {
            ArrayList < String > ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
            ArrayList < String > purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
            ArrayList < String > signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
            String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

            if (purchaseDataList.size() > 0) {
                // Item(s) owned

                for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                    String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                    //  String signature = signatureList.get(i); // Note
                    // signatures
                    // do not
                    // appear to
                    // work with
                    // android.test.purchased
                    // (silly
                    // google)
                    String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                    Log.e("----->>", purchaseData + " --- " + " --- " + sku);
                }
            } else {
                // Item(s) not owned

                Toast.makeText(this, "No any Item is purchased",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            // Error checking owned items
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the primary gmail account set on device to use google play is same then it will work. So when you do getPurchase() you will returned with the purchases item details, and you need to verify the developer payload for validity of the item.

Comment: yes i can able to get purchased item from getPurchase() , but if i use different device with the same account then i cant

Comment: @Vaishali I think its contains security scenarios, as per my point of view, you can not do this with 2 device at a time.

Comment: i donot check both at the same time... it is possible for this in different time ?

Comment: @Vaishali I think then it may work but google account must be same in both devices.

Comment: no it will not work ...
i have try it also .. and i  have already use same account

Comment: @Vaishali Then I think you have to read policy guidelines for it, because first of all you need to know that is that possible or not??

Comment: @pratik , i have read it also .. there not any point mentioned for different device

Comment: @Vaishali I think this whole process is working on device token?? or have you checked proper that Device A is loggedout from that account.

Comment: yes i check it after doing logout from device A.. and thats not working with device id..

Comment: @Vaishali http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-install-paid-apps-on-multiple-android-devices/ please read this I hope you would found something useful.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51689/how-many-devices-does-one-purchase-of-android-app-support

Comment: @Vaishali found something useful or not?

Comment: no :( cant able to get

Comment: @Vaishali ohhh still not done with this dear?

Comment: @Vaishali I think need to read more about this one. Because as per I have heard, once you purchased any app using one account then you might not be purchase second time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263889/does-in-app-billing-support-multiple-accounts read this

Comment: @Vaishali I think its the bug from google play, its not your fault.

Comment: @Vaishali is this working or not still?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                // String signature = signatureList.get(i);

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);

                String skuId = jo.getString("productId");
                int purchaseState = -1;
                if (jo.getString("purchaseState").length() > 0) {
                    purchaseState = Integer.parseInt(jo
                            .getString("purchaseState"));
                } else {
                    purchaseState = -1;
                }
                System.out.println("skuId::" + skuId + " purchaseState"
                        + purchaseState);
                InApp.addPurchasedItem(rootContext, skuId, purchaseState);
                valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                valueMap.put("productId", listOfProductId.get(i));
                valueMap.put("isProductPurchased", ""
                        + ((purchaseState == 0) ? "true" : "false"));
                hashListGotProudctList.add(valueMap);

                // do something with this purchase information
                // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by
                // user
            }
```